# What is the proper UX for user to exit an iPhone app?

Tags: ios

Is the iPhone "device Home button" (circle button that is part of the hardware at bottom center) the standard way that users exit an iPhone app?

I don't have an actual iPhone device yet *(looking for the iPhone6 to come down in price a bit)*, am just working with Xcode simulators.  When I run my iPhone Swift apps, they are always in full screen mode.

On Android, there are a few navigation buttons built into the OS that appear at the bottom of the screen - Back, Home, Open Apps.  And in that OS you can give a directive to exit full screen to reveal those OS buttons.. which then allows the user to easily exit the app if they'd like to.

In looking at the iPhone apps on the simulator, I notice they don't have this kind of UX.

What are the best practices around iPhone users

A. Sending an app to the background ?

B. Quitting/Closing an app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send an app to the background, hitting the home button is sufficient.

To quit an app, tapping the home button twice shows you all the open apps; you can then swipe an app to "kill" (terminate) it.

However, here is a recent post by the excellent John Gruber explaining why killing an app should only be a last resort: https://daringfireball.net/2017/07/you_should_not_force_quit_apps

Note: on the iPhone Simulator, the command-shift-H key combo is equivalent to hitting the home button.

Comment: Pretty good answer, but I ended up adding my own anyway... can't underscore enough that "force quit" is not part of the expected UX for iOS.

Comment: FYI - Double-tapping the Home button does not show you a list of open apps. It shows you a list of recently used apps (minus ones you've recently force-quit).

Answer (score 2):

#### To send an app to the background:

1. Press the Home button.

#### To "quit" or "close" an app:

1. Press the Home button.

That's all the UX expected of an iOS app... and none if it is actually provided by your app. iOS manages it for you; you just have to deal with your app's [lifecycle methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate) to respond to the user leaving and re-entering your app.

---

iOS doesn't expect users to know or care about the difference between "background" and "closed/quit" in most cases. You enter an app, you leave an app, that's it.

And the way iOS works under the hood, there *is no difference* in most cases — when you leave an app, it's not "running in the background", it's "frozen" or "suspended": that is, in memory but not running. That way the OS can get it usable again near-instantly if the user comes back, or instantly reclaim that memory if another process needs it.

The user can also invoke the multitasking UI (double click home button, or in iOS 11 on iPad swipe up from bottom edge) and swipe an app away, but this is equivalent to the "kill" or "force quit" actions seen in other operating systems — it's primarily for situations where an app is misbehaving. This isn't part of your app's UX either; it's also provided by iOS.

As noted in [the Daring Fireball post](https://daringfireball.net/2017/07/you_should_not_force_quit_apps) linked from [@TimKokesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45245340/957768), there are some circumstances where an app "in the background" isn't "frozen" but has some limited ability to run, the Settings app has UI to help the user keep tabs on what are using (and abusing) that ability, and those are some of the only cases where it's reasonable for a user to "force quit" apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a real iPhone look-alike simulator on your development environment, yes it's available with New **Xcode-9/Beta version**. It shows real hardware buttons(volume, lock, home buttons) which you can press and feel like a real device. If you are interested you can download it from [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/)

On other Xcode environments, you can go to home screen by pressing the keys: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>